Recommended solution for sveltekit and websocket
i have decision to make in my app in regards to sockets. I have read some articles and posts about this but i still wasn't sure which way to go. So, I have an app in which game master can start games, i make api call to the backend where i update my database. Now after i update my database i would like to send events to currently logged in users that were in a list that i have sent to that server.
For my particular case (im using sveltekit ssr) would socket.io or websocket be more suitable? And what is the best way to handle it and its state in sveltekit? I have so far thought of putting my server logic in the hooks.server.ts but im not sure how to handle the connections.
